# Progressive downloading

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a JQuery mobile application using asp.net MVC 4 razor. In my application,there are list of images saved in database.

Is it possible to show these images in view in progressive manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I understand for your question is you do not want to load images which are outside of viewport (visible part of web page). **You want to lazy load your images.**

**Check this jQuery plugin:**

[Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

**[See Working Demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html)**

Lazy Load is a jQuery plugin written in JavaScript. It delays loading of images in long web pages. **Images outside of viewport (visible part of web page) wont be loaded before user scrolls to them.** This is opposite of image preloading.

Using Lazy Load on long web pages containing many large images makes the page load faster. Browser will be in ready state after loading visible images. In some cases it can also help to reduce server load.

Comment: Thanks for reply...In lazy load images are loaded prior right?